# CMFCListctrl Sorting

Tags: mfc

In CMFCListCtrl, I am adding sorting arrow image in the header by calling the function SetSortColumn().

Now the problem is when sort arrow image  is getting displayed, the header text is not getting  visible fully.

How to adjust/expand  the size of header programmatically on displaying sort arrow?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: One of solution - you should override OnDrawItem(...) method in your subclassed CMFCHeaderCtrl class (list header class) to draw it manually whatever you want.

Comment: I would suggest to give the columns a larger width from start on...

Comment: Try to call `SetColumnWidth(n, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)`. I'm not sure if it correctly works with the sort image, as this is propably owner-drawn by MFC code.

Comment: Just had a look into "afxheaderctrl.cpp" MFC source from VS2017. There isn't any code that tells the system the required minimum size of the header item depending on whether sort arrow is shown. The drawing code is pretty much hardcoded pre-high-dpi-era stuff like `rectArrow.DeflateRect(5, 5)` (eek!). Best to avoid the beast alltogether.

Comment: I would set the size of the checkbox from the system metrics and add that width. Or, see if there is an auto size function that does it automatically. I use `CGridCtrl` and it auto sizes automatically.

Comment: Possible alternative: implement sorting yourself and set header item flags [`HDF_SORTUP` or `HDF_SORTDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-_hd_itema). These arrows are shown *above* the text, so they do not get in the way like the ones of `CMFCListCtrl`.

Answer (score 1):

The internal code shows that the item height of the header control -5 is used for the room of the sort symbol.

see CMFCHeaderCtrl::OnDrawItem.

```
    // Draw sort arrow:
    CRect rectArrow = rect;
    rectArrow.DeflateRect(5, 5);
    rectArrow.left = rectArrow.right - rectArrow.Height();
```

So enlarging all items by this size will help.

This should work. Calculate the height of of use font, multiply by 1.5 and add this to the width of the column.